# I can't see my Samsung Smart TV anymore for wireless screen mirroring with Windows via a specific router

Tags: mirroring, screencasts, miracast, smart-tv

I was able to connect my TV (*Samsung 40N5300*) without any problem. The only problem was, it was disconnected sometimes. It's not like a timeout period since there is no specific for disconnection: It could be disconnected after 20 minutes or 2 minutes. To handle this problem, I went to **Device Manager** and found the ethernet device there, unchecked `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power`. I'm not sure it's exactly because of after that, but my computer stopped seeing my Samsung TV. My computer is connected via ethernet (and also WiFi) and my TV is connected via WiFi on the same router.

To handle this problem:

- Re-check `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` on etherner
- Unchecked/checked `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power` on WiFi device which is Intel AX201
- Tried to update the ethernet, WiFi, GPU drivers on **Device Manager** but it said all updated
- Tried to update GPU from **GeForce Experience** but there was no update
- Downloaded **Intel Driver Support Assistant** and I found that there are 2 updates, I updated
- I deleted memorized devices from **Device Connect Manager** from Samsung Smart TV

Still not on the Wireless Display list (`Ctrl+K`).

But my MacBook easily sees the TV and connect (also there is no disconnection issue). And when I connect my TV and my Windows to another router, Windows can see the TV. But not on my main router which is *Asus RT-AX58U*.

I'm looking forward to your advice.

Comment: "not on my main modem which is Asus RT-AX58U" did you restart the modem?

Comment: @DavidPostill Of course; the modem starts by itself every night. But I just restarted again because of your comment, no luck

Comment: Not really a modem but a router and likely the other one you mention is also a router. When connected to the one where you don't see the TV are the TV and the PC in the same network? Same routers have the WiFi isolation feature (AKA guest AP). Are you sure you AREN'T connecting the TV to a guest AP and the PC connected normally via Ethernet? BTW, if you have both as you mentioned (for no reason whatsoever) typically Ethernet takes precedence.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I changed "modem" to "router", thanks. Let me give you more details: My Asus router broadcasts both 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz. I have also Mi router, which also broadcasts two band ranges. My desktop is connected to Asus via ethernet. My TV was connected to Asus via 5Ghz. I could screen mirror w/out any problem. Then somehow my computer stopped seeing my TV. If I connect the TV and computer to Mi router (both 5Ghz wireless), the computer can list the TV. Same as 2.4Ghz. I even tried to connect the TV to Asus 2.4Ghz and the computer via ethernet, the computer can list the TV.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Also I would like to explain why I'm using two different routers. Asus router directly broadcast normal internet I'm getting from ISP. On the other hand, the Mi router first gets an IP from a remote computer (other than my country), then broadcasts that internet. Basically, all the devices using the Mi router get a VPN connection automatically.